# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in you

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, mysql-error-1064

```
  $wordsAry = explode(" ", $search);
$wordsCount = count($wordsAry);
$queryCondition = " WHERE ";
for($i=0;$i<$wordsCount;$i++) {
    $queryCondition .= "`location` LIKE '%$wordsAry[$i]%'";
    if($i!=$wordsCount-1) {
        $queryCondition .= " OR ";
    }
}
echo $queryCondition;

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `shelves_instruments` 
:szukaj
ORDER BY location ASC";
$licz_ilosc = $connect_db -> prepare($sql1);
$licz_ilosc -> bindValue(':szukaj', $queryCondition, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$licz_ilosc -> execute(); 
$ilosc_stron = $licz_ilosc->rowCount();
```

> WHERE `location` LIKE '%walida%'

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException:
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' WHERE
> `location` LIKE '%walida%'' ORDER BY location ASC' at line 2 in

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepared statements aren't a fancy way of substituting text. You can't send an entire `WHERE` clause as a single parameter.

You need to create a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
$where = "WHERE `location` like :term1 OR `location` like :term2";
```

Then create your terms such that

```
     $param1 = '%'.$firstTerm.'%'  ;
     $param2 = '%'.$secondTerm.'%'  ;
```

Then bind your terms to your prepared statement

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `shelves_instruments` ".$where." ORDER BY location ASC"
$licz_ilosc = $connect_db -> prepare($query);
$licz_ilosc->execute([
    "term1"=>$param1,
    "term2"=>$param2
]);
```

Comment: Outstanding answer! You figured out what the questioner was trying to do, and gave him (and us all) the conceptual framework to get it right.